# Temporarily merge the batch dimension in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, reshape

I have a Keras model that has in input shape of `[None, 500, 500, 3]` and output shape of `[None, 1]`. Now, I want to make a wrapper model that has an input shape of `[None, 48, 500, 500, 3]`, and output shape of `[None, 48]`.

To do that, the naive way is to iterate 48 times on the second axis and apply the first model, then use Keras' `Concatenate` layer to get the desired shape.

```py
model_outputs = []
for i in range(inputs.shape[1]):
    im_block = inputs[:, i]
    model_outputs += [self.model(im_block)]
return Concatenate()(model_outputs)
```

However, this makes the graph quite complicated. So I would like to do the following instead:

```
        [None, 48, 500, 500, 3]
     -> [None*48,  500, 500, 3]
           (apply the model)
     -> [None*48,  1]
     -> [None, 48, 1]
```

My attempt at that is

```py
outputs = tf.reshape(inputs, (inputs[0] * inputs[1], *inputs[2:]))
outputs = self.model(outputs)
outputs = tf.reshape(outputs, (inputs[0], inputs[1]))
return outputs
```

But this gives me

```
TypeError: Cannot iterate over a tensor with unknown first dimension.
```

Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
inp = tf.reshape(inp, (-1, 500, 500, 3))
res = model(inp)
res = tf.reshape(res, (-1, 48))
```

Comment: You're right, I just forgot `.shape` and was using the tensor's value, which don't exist..